# How to get truncated-to-integer division in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, floating-point, decimal

The following code keeps producing 5ft 11.8in instead of 4ft 11.8in when I type in 152 cm. I thought it was the floating point inaccuracies at first so I tried using decimal but that also gives me the same value. Is there anyway to make it more accurate? The number in height before it is divided by 12 is 59.84251....

```
class Height
{
    private decimal height;
    private string unit;
    public static string ConvertedHeight(decimal height, string unit)
    {
        if (unit == "m")
        {
            height = height * 100 / 2.54m;
            string conversion = (height / 12).ToString("F0") + "ft " + (height % 12).ToString("F1") + "in/n";
            return conversion;
        }
        else if (unit == "cm")
        {
            height = height / 2.54m;
            string conversion = (height / 12).ToString("F0") + "ft " + (height % 12).ToString("F1") + "in/n";
            return conversion;
```

Comment: `Decimal.Divide(decimal, decimal)` implicitly converts its arguments to decimals before returning a decimal value (precise)

Comment: Wrt. the above: check out the *actual* value of `height / 12`, not the displayed result after the string formatting. Compare this with `(int)height / 12`; what is the type of resulting expression in both cases?

Comment: I request those who voted to close as “can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error” show us which characters were mistyped or show us what results they get when `ConvertedHeight` is called with the arguments 152 and "cm".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need cast your feet conversation to `int` in this case.

This is the code you need for division by 12.

```
(int) (height / 12)
```

Hope this helps!